# Page/Div Content fade in and out on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been working on my recruiting website for some days now. I am a newbie in programming. Please I need script that will load the Employment review content fade out on click of of each employment vacancy div and fade in on clicking "close" on the Employment review content page. Thanks.

[image: Employment Vacancy Page]
[image: Employment Vacancy Listing]

Comment: StackOverflow isn't a place to have code written for you. You need to have some code which you have tried with the issue you're running into with it. Please update your question to include what you've already tried.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery to achieve that like this: http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/

```
$( "#vacancy-div-id" ).click(function() {
  $( "#id-of-what-you-want-to-fade-out" ).fadeOut( "slow", function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

To fade in you can use this: http://api.jquery.com/fadein/

```
$( "#close-button-id" ).click(function() {
  $( "#id-of-what-you-want-to-fade-in" ).fadeIn( "slow", function() {
    // Animation complete
  });
});
```

More detailed example - Put this in your html:

```
<script>
    $( "#close-button-id" ).click(function() {
      $( "#id-of-what-you-want-to-fade-in" ).fadeIn( "slow", function() {
        // Animation complete
      });
    });
</script>
```

If you do not know the id of what you want to be click to trigger the fadeIn animation, you can right click on the element and click inspect, it will show to you the html of your page.

Comment: Pls how am I going to do that? I am sort of confused.

Comment: do you have experience with javascript / jquery? What language are you using on your site?

Comment: I see you are using php. You can open in your html a script tag <script></script> And use this code to get the click events and callbacks

Comment: If it helped please give an upvote :) And feel free to ask if you are still in doubt.

Comment: Hi Gabriel, thank you so much. I stated learning web 3 weeks ago on my own.  I just posted a screenshot of what the employment vacancy listing code looks like. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nx4p7.png

Comment: I actually wanted to call the employment vacancy listings from the database to show on the listing page but seem so dificult for me so I added them manually in the html.

Comment: Ok so as you said, you need to fade out when " click of of each employment vacancy div  ". So take this div and give an id property just like class. Then you can replace "vacancy-div-id" in my code, for the id you created

Comment: To make this code work you need to open an script tag in your html. Look at this examples, they are really simple: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_click.asp

Comment: I also recommend you to start from here: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp

Comment: So @cHlSecurity I gave a lot of links to help you. I cannot write the code for you, since i do not know your application. But you are in the correct way. Start from scratch with this link:  w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp And you learn how to use jquery in your app. Remember to give an upvote on my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    #start{
        height:100px;
        width:300px;
        border:3px solid red;
        display: none;

    }
    #start.fadeIn{
        display: block;
        animation-name:fadein;
        animation-duration:3s;
    }
@keyframes fadein {
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}

document.getElementById('run').addEventListener('click',function(){
        document.getElementById('start').classList.toggle('fadeIn');
    })


<div id="start" class="rotating">
            some text  some text  some text  some text  some text
    </div>
```